# How do you fix a cannot lock ref due to an illegal character "|" on Windows?

Tags: windows, git

```
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/Reopening-|-Header-Covid': Unable to create 'C:/Projects/website/.git/refs/remotes/origin/Reopening-|-Header-Covid.lock': Invalid argument
```

How do you fix a cannot lock ref due to an illegal character "|" on Windows?

I tried everything I saw relating to cannot lock ref, but the problem is different because it's caused by an illegal character and not some data corruption. How do you fix this?

Comment: When does this occur? Does it happen when you run _any_ command against a local copy, or only when you run specific commands? If so, which ones?

Comment: The best way for now is to not have such names. Get whoever made the branch on the other Git to rename it before you get the branch name on your end. Obviously that's a little late now... You might be able to open `.git/packed-refs` in a text editor (be sure it's in plain-text mode) and delete the line with the bad name, but until the name is fixed over on `origin`, it will keep coming back.

Comment: There's a project to revamp ref storage for Git, that should fix this without these kinds of tricks, but I have no idea if / when it will become generally available. I'm not even sure how you can experiment with it even if you build your own Git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default implementation of Git stores its references either in the file system or in a packed refs file, depending on how the data is stored.  In this case, the remote server has a branch with the pipe character, which Windows does not permit in file names, so such a file cannot be stored in the file system.  Windows has similar problems with refs which differ only in case.

There is work on a set of patches for a format called *reftable* which does not suffer from these problems, but that work is not yet complete and it's unknown if it will ever be.  In the mean time, there are some possible options:

- Ignore the error.  You won't be able to work with the ref in any meaningful way.
- Ask the owner of the remote to rename or delete the ref.
- Use the Windows Subsystem for Linux.
- Use another operating system.  Unix systems permit the pipe character, although macOS by default still suffers from the case-insensitivity problem.

Comment: "reftable" appears to have [somewhat landed](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/reftable#_version_1), though I haven't checked if it helps here.

Comment: Reftable will help here, but it's not in actual use and I don't think it's fully functional.